# Help me solve riddle - "What am I"

Tags: riddle

> I get bigger
>  the farther away you are
>  but if you get too far away
>  I don't exist.

**What am I?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! It looks like this riddle is from somewhere else. Could you please give the source for it?

Comment: It's an event in discord community im in, it's a series of riddles.

Comment: @Puzzzzz Is this a competitive event, or a "for fun" thing? If it's an ongoing competition, then I'm afraid our rules don't allow us to provide answers, as it's not fair to the other competitors.

Comment: there isn't any reward for completing this puzzle if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 7):

> The horizon?

Explanation:

> As you get further from the earth, you can see more of it at once; It therefore takes up a greater percentage of your field of view. However, once you are high enough, what you see of the earth cannot be properly described as the horizon. We could say that it no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is

> Your *shadow*

If you are close to

> your shadow, it's fairly small

If you get far away

> from your shadow, it looks bigger

If you get too far away,

> as in closer to the sun, you'd die from lack of oxygen. Also, your shadow would become indistinct because of the sun's size.

Here's another guess:

> *age*. The farther you get in life, the bigger it gets. If you die, you don't really have one.

Comment: i tried shadow but it is not the right answer.

Comment: @Puzzzzz I threw in another try.

Comment: age is also wrong

Answer (score 0):

> I am Shadow and you are light.

Answer (score 0):

> "I" am "your" shadow.
> The further you are from the light, the longer your shadow.  But if you get too far away, there is no light, and therefore no shadow.